# Issues importing mplcursors

Tags: python, mplcursors

I successfully installed mplcursors
[image]

however why am I still can't import the mplcursors?
[image]

Comment: Please share copy-and-pasted error messages and code, not screenshots.

Comment: looks like you might need `python3 py.py`

Comment: it says: python3 : The term 'python3' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ python3 py.py
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (python3:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: Either way this error normally means you have more than one version of python installed

Comment: what should i do, should I uninstall python and start it over?

Comment: use a virtualenv. **ALWAYS** use a virtualenv so you're always sure you're running in the correct context